# Pulling from Upstream into empty master causes merging

Tags: git, merge

I´m pretty new to git. I´ve got an empty master branch. And now I tried to pull something from an extern upstream with:

```
git pull upstream master
```

The result is that an editor opens, and says:

> Merge branch 'master' of .....
>   Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
>   especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.

But why should I merge something when my master branch is empty? What´s my mistake?
If I close the editor the terminal says:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects:71, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
remote: Total 71 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (71/71), done.
```

Is this correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you just do something like `git init` && `git  remote add upstream <PATH>` && `git pull upstream master`? What does `git log master` show before pulling?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabcyk Yes, i used `git init`, `git clone`, `git remote add upstream` and finally `git pull`. After git clone there´s just an empty folder!
`git log master` shows 
`commit xxxx
Author: xxxx
Date:   Fri Oct 2 11:53:51 2015 +0200

    initial commit. just added empty .gitignore file`

Answer (score 0):

You only git pull from "`upstream`" if you have cloned from "`origin`" first.

This is the triangular workflow, made [more accessible with git 2.5](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows#improved-support-for-triangular-workflows) with the new command line shorthand `<reference>@{push}`:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/8943755/5dcdcae4-354a-11e5-9f82-915914fad4f7.png]

So clone a **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)** first (and your master branch won't be empty)

*Then* pull from upstream (to update your master branch with the latest content of the original upstream repo)

---

> To see what commits you've added to your current branch since the last push:

```
$ git log @{push}..
```

> This uses the new `@{push}` notation, which denotes the current value of the remote-tracking branch that the current branch would be pushed to by git push, namely `origin/whizbang`.
>   You can also refer to the push destination of an arbitrary branch using the notation `whizbang@{push}`.